# How to simulate real world stress test scenario

Tags: java, http, microservices, load-testing, stress-testing

It's difficult to simulate a real stress scenario when every micro-service is under stress. Generally in load test, there's only few micro-service which are under stress and not all the micro-services. Is there any way we can increase the response time of all the outgoing calls from my service, so that it's easy to estimate the actual response time of my service during a load test  or any way how to implement that.

I havent tried anything because i dont have any clue about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complex application built on top of [microservice architecture pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) be aware that it will always act on speed of its **slowest component**.

So your goal is not to stress all the microservices, but to determine what is the slowest one. Once done you can investigate the reason, suggest and/or implement the fix and repeat the test until you will be satisfied with the result.

The best approach would be going for stress testing of the whole integrated system, starting from 1 virtual user and increasing the load until transport starts queuing up at [ingress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingress_router) of one of the microservices.

Once you figure out which is the slowest microservice you should be able to stress-test it separately and use [monitoring](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) or [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tools in order to determine the [bottleneck](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/wp-rapid-1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider two of these options.

Gatling - https://www.baeldung.com/load-test-a-website-with-gatling

JMeter - https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/